# Datatype changed After server change

Tags: laravel, api, response

I had created some API's using laravel and then changed server and transfer all files to other server which is AWS ec2 but after changing server API's response datatype changes so its getting errors in IOS app.

Below is the response before server change

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "Id": "127",
            "Title": "Test",
            "AuthorName": "Test",
            "AuthorDesignation": "dg",
            "Description": "Test",
            "Image": "1535538907.JPG",
            "MediaType": "0",
            "Date": "2018-08-29 05:35:07",
            "Status": "1",
            "DonateLink": null,
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-29 10:35:07",
            "delete_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "Thumbnail": "1535538907.JPG"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": "",
    "path": "myurl/api/news",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": "",
    "to": 5,
    "total": 5,
    "status": true
}
```

After changed the server below is the response

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "Id": 127,
            "Title": "Test",
            "AuthorName": "Test",
            "AuthorDesignation": "dg",
            "Description": "test",
            "Image": "1535538907.JPG",
            "MediaType": 0,
            "Date": "2018-08-29 10:35:07",
            "Status": 1,
            "DonateLink": null,
            "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-29 15:35:07",
            "delete_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "Thumbnail": "1535538907.JPG"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": "",
    "path": "my_url/api/news",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": "",
    "to": 5,
    "total": 5,
    "status": true
}
```

The Issue is that `ID`,`MediaType`,`Status` all changed from `string` to `int`.how could i get back response with same datatype.

Comment: It seems like your new server also brought some other service upgrades.
You may however cast these values to string explicitly, but imho it feels correct to have int values there.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Is there any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've also changed the PHP version to 7.x+ and your functions/methods are using type-hinting?

Unlike the previous versions of PHP, 7+ versions allow you to type-hint strings, ints, etc and PHP would try to convert the value to the appropriate type. For example:

```
public function test(string $name)
```

expects a string and even if you pass test(1), you will still receive a string with a value of 1. The other way around is also valid, if you pass a string "1" and the function expects an int, it will try to cast it to an int.

You can easily check if this is the case by enabling the PHP strict mode by adding

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
```

In strict mode, PHP will rise a TypeError exception, so it would probably break your code, but you will now this is what is causing the issue.

In any case, as Tschitsch commented, you can always type cast the integers to strings, but it does indeed look like these should be ints, rather than strings.

Comment: Okay so i have to typecast manually? or is there any direct solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of any automatic solution, I'm afraid